# TryParse in Switch-Case Statement

Tags: c#

I'm making a calculator, and I'm using a switch-case statement to determine what to do when the user clicks a button. When the user just presses a number (0-9) then I want to simply just add the number to the end of the current string. This was an easy task, although I was wondering if there's an easier way to evaluate if a string is a number in a `case` statement.

In other words, can I simplify the following:

```
case "0":
case "1":
case "2":
case "3":
case "4":
case "5":
case "6":
case "7":
case "8":
case "9":

//code to execute here
```

I know I can call `TryParse` earlier on and run a separate block of code, but I was wondering if there was a way to do something such as `case myString.TryParse():`

Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: You can add `0,9` case in default.

Comment: Try read something about the new C# 7.x features, e.g. [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) It can be used in cases. I think I saw there some description, that might help you with your problem, but I can not find now the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give it a try to use [pattern matching](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/01/pattern-matching.aspx), but I think specifying as in original post should be much faster, so I don't recommend it, but you can in fact do what you asked:

```
string a = "5";
switch (a)
{
   case var digit when char.IsDigit(a[0]):
     var intDigit = int.Parse(digit);
     ...
     break;
   ...
   <other cases>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are definitely going the long way around when there are simple libraries already able to handle this :)

try `System.Char.IsDigit(numericChar)`

There are many other ways to do this easily, just google around for a bit :)

Comment: Proper method name is `char.IsDigit(numericChar)` (`isDigit` is for Java).

Comment: Yeah lazy on the casing, my bad ^^

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that some buttons have strings that are more than one character long, i.e. “CA” which stands for clear all

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements aren't suited for looking for multiple possible values, you would be better of with a bunch of if else statements

```
if(Char.IsDigit(inputString))
{

}
else if(someCondition)
{
}
else if(someCondition2)
{
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `inputChar` instead of `inputString`?